# The noticeError method was not found. while using Coldbox and NewRelic for Error tracking

Tags: exception, coldfusion, newrelic, coldbox

I'm just using `NewRelic` error trapping for my `coldbox` application. From `OnException` method, I'm just sending the error struct to log the error.

My code in onexception method

```
public function onException(event,rc,prc){
 NewRelic.logError( prc.exception.getExceptionStruct());
}
```

The logerror() method resides in NewRelic.cfc and contains the following code

```
 public boolean function logError(
  required struct exception
) {
  var cause = arguments.exception;
  var params = {  
    error_id =  createUUID(), 
    type: arguments.exception.type,
    message: arguments.exception.message
    };

    writeDump(this.newRelic);
    this.newRelic.noticeError(cause, params);abort;
    return true;
}
```

So while error, I'm gettig the following error.

> The noticeError method was not found.

[image]

You can see that, the `noticeError()` method is there in the object, but it is overloaded with arguments.

**I'm using the same code for NewRelic error trapping in another coldfusion project without any frameworks.**

Calling `error.cfm` through `Cferror` tag, and the code in error.cfm as follows

```
<cfset Application.newRelic.logError( variables.error )>
```

And in NewRelic.cfc, the `logerror()` method contains the same code as in the coldbox application. **But it is logging errors in NewRelic without any issues.**

This is the method I need to notice errors and log it in NewRelic.

> noticeError(java.lang.Throwable, java.util.Map)

So I just thought to get the classname of the first argument `Cause` through the following code from both applications within logError() in NewRelic.cfc, to get the difference.

```
writeDump(cause.getClass().getName());
```

I'm getting

`coldfusion.runtime.ExceptionScope` for Coldbox application
and
`coldfusion.runtime.UndefinedVariableException` for normal coldfusion application

The `cause` argument is not throwable from coldbox application. So how to get the original error struct from coldbox application? and make it throwable to fix the `noticeError method was not found` issue.

Comment: It's a known issue in ColdFusion: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3976478. Adobe are not interested in fixing it.

Comment: @AdamCameron Oh! okay, Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change in the underlying class happens when ColdBox duplicates the error object with CFML's `duplicate()` method.  I doubt that ColdFusion behavior is documented anywhere, but I don't see an easy way to get around it right now other than creating your own instance of a java.langException and populating it with the details of the original error.

If you want to modify the ColdBox core code, this happens here:
https://github.com/ColdBox/coldbox-platform/blob/master/system/web/context/ExceptionBean.cfc#L43

I have entered this ticket for the ColdBox framework for us to review if we can stop duplicating the error object in future versions of the framework.

https://ortussolutions.atlassian.net/browse/COLDBOX-476

Update: Adam Cameron pointed out this ticket in the Adobe bug tracker that details this behavior in the engine.  It was closed as "neverFix".

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3976478

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and ticket creation with respect to the issue  Let me try, if there is any other work around.

Comment: FYI: COLDBOX-476 has been fixed on the bleeding edge release of ColdBox and will go out in our 4.2.0 release once it is stable.  This fix removes the duplicate() call and thus works around the ColdFusion behavior.

Comment: I got solution for this issue on coldbox 4.2.0,  and now my coldbox application logs error on Newrelic.